# Error with installation of Cytoscape 3.8.2 in Windows 10

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I would like to ask for any help with the installation of `Cytoscape 3.8.2` in Windows 10.
I tried to download from [here](https://cytoscape.org/download.html) and I get this error when I run the install4j Wizard:

```
[Error downloading the Java Runtime Environment. Please check your internet connection and start setup again
Log: C:\Users\Victor\Appdata\Local\Temp\i4j_nlog_13.log][1]
```

I tried to download the windows.bat from the Troubleshooting section but it's only download as .txt. I open the terminal and paste the text from windows.bat but it does not run.
It must some easy mistake of beginner but I cannot figure out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There may have been an https certificate expiration that affected some of the JRE downloads for Cytoscape Desktop. It has been updated. Could you try again?